# Support for emojis in LIGO?

Tags: michelson, ligo

Is LIGO going to get native support for emojis?

When I tried compiling a contract with the classic  (rocketship emoji) inside a string, I got the error `Unexpected character '\240'`.

Honestly, without , , or , how can we even crypto? /s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [string type](https://tezos.gitlab.io/michelson-reference/#type-string) in Michelson is restricted to :

> [...] the printable subset of 7-bit ASCII, namely characters with codes from within [32, 126] range, plus the following escape characters \n, \, ".

As LIGO compiles to Michelson, we'll not have emojis in LIGO.

How, indeed, will we crypto?

But, do not fret! A major advantage of Tezos compared to other blockchains is its [upgradability](https://tezos.com/get-started#self-amendment). Anyone can develop and propose a protocol amendment. Such an amendment could expand strings to include Emoji.

PS: you could use [bytes](https://tezos.gitlab.io/michelson-reference/#type-bytes).